# "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I just put my asp .net web service on a remote host. The service accesses an oracle db on my local machine. The service worked fine when it was running on localhost but since moving to a remote hos, I get

```
The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client at
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize() at
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at....
```

I know the error is related to the data provider version running on the server/client. In my case, the only dll I referenced in the project was Oracle.DataAccess

So how do I go about solving this? Note that I won't be able to change anything on the web host other than my own project.

My local machine is running Oracle 11g

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Find out what version of the Oracle client is running at your web host's site.  If it's an old client you either need to

```
A) get your web host to update their software to something more up-to-date,
B) downgrade to an older version of Oracle that their client can deal with, or
C) change web hosts.
```

Good luck.